# Typescript find() and return index

Tags: typescript, find

Is it possible to return the array index using the array.find() method in typescript?

eg, I have an array of objects and can return an object using find on a object property name, but can I also somehow return the index of that item in the array?

Comment: Use `.findIndex()` instead of `.find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answers are correct that to get index you use `.findIndex()` & to get the actual entry of the array you use `.find()`

However, it seems to me like you are asking how to get the index plus the entry in the array at once.

If I am correct you can try something like:

```
    let array  = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
                
    let tuesday = array.map((day,index) => {
       if(day == "Tuesday")
         return {day, index}
    }).filter(day => day)[0];

    console.log(tuesday);
```

You should get back an object with the entry & the index like this:

```
{"day": "Tuesday", "index": 2}
```

I am not sure if this is the cleanest way of getting them both at once, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

### **For finding index, you could use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex?retiredLocale=vi)**

**Something like this:**

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

console.log(array1.findIndex((element) => element > 13));
```

**And then to get actual value from that Index:**

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];

const idx = array1.findIndex((element) => element > 13);

console.log(array1[idx])
```

Comment: Why is everything in your question bold?

Comment: My keyboard is broken

Answer (score 1):

`find` returns the element. `findIndex` returns the index.

`findIndex` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex